# What does int** mean in C in this context?

Tags: c++, c, pointers

Here is the context:

```
int *t[10];
int n;
```

I am being told that `t-n` is of the type int**.
I don't exactly get what int** means, is it a pointer of a pointer? Why would the subtraction of a table of pointers - int would give a pointer of pointer of an int? When we refer to `*t[0]` do we refer to `int* p` to the pointer itself because it is an element of the table or do we implicitly need a pointer to point at the slot than have the pointer point to the another place?

Thanks in advance for explaining this to me.

Comment: *is it a pointer of a pointer?* Yup. That's it. Kinda weird for a beginner, I guess but that's that it is. Basically you need to dereference it. However, without a [Minimal, Reproducible, Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), we can't really help you any further.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I don't exactly get what `int**` means, is it a pointer of a pointer?

Yes.

- `int` = integer
- `int *` = pointer-to-integer
- `int **` = pointer-to-(pointer-to-integer)
- `int ***` = pointer-to-(pointer-to-(pointer-to-integer))
- (and so on)

> Why would the subtraction of a table of pointers - int would give a
>   pointer of pointer of an int?

Because in C (and C++), an array decays into a pointer to the first item when necessary.  For example, `int *t[10]` is an array of 10 pointer-to-int items.  `t` can decay into a pointer to `t[0]`, ie a pointer-to-(pointer-to-int), `int **`. That pointer can then be used for pointer arithmetic (like subtraction).

So, subtracting `n` from `t` would give you an `int **` that is pointing `n` items "before" the beginning of your 10-item array (which BTW would not be a safe pointer to use, unless `n` was zero or a small negative number, since it would be pointing outside the valid bounds of the array's memory).

> When we refer to `*t[0]` do we refer to `int* p` to the pointer itself
>   because it is an element of the table or do we implicitly need a
>   pointer to point at the slot than have the pointer point to the
>   another place?

I'm not sure I understand this question.  Since `t[10]` is an array of 10 pointers (i.e. 10 `int *`'s), that means that `t[0]` is a single item in that array and therefore has type `int *`.  Therefore `*t[0]` dereferences the first pointer in the array, yielding the actual `int` value that the pointer is pointing to.

Answer (score 0):

> what `int**` means

It's the type of a pointer to a pointer to an `int`. If you dereference a variable `t` of this type (like this: `*t`), you get a pointer to an `int`. If you dereference it twice (like this: `**t`), you get an `int`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have `TYPE a[N];`, the array expression `a`, if evaluated, produces a pointer of type `T *`, pointing to `a[0]`. This is sometimes called C's array-to-pointer "decay" rule.

If `TYPE` is `int *`, as in your case, then `TYPE *` is `int **`.

Since your array is of `int *` pointers, the pointer which indexes into the array is a necessarily pointer to that element type.